# Uiautomator запуск на телефоне без android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

мне нравится концепция uiautomator, мне интересно управление другими приложениями, я хочу запустить тест в не A Studio, без adb, скажем по клику в приложении. **Как это сделать?**
я видел это делают при промощи .jar фаила, ноя не знаю как создать jar.фаил Android Studio 3.1.2.
вотак это выглядит, через терминал - adb shell uiautomator runtest  -c  [options].
пример - adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings.
вот ссылка https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html 
**чем еще можно управлять другими приложениями в системе android?**

Answer (score 0):

Цитирую ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419540/5892568
Использование UI Automator осложнено тем что надо запускать со специальными привилегиями из ADB shell.

Как идея используя adb wifi теоретически с другого сервиса вы можете сделать этот вызов, послав команду из основного приложения.

Кроме того неясен сценарий использования, что именно вы хотите делать из приложения? Не проще пользователю дать подсказку что и как сделать?

Comment: использовать это для того чтобы мне позвонил вотсап по событию.UI Automator надо использовать полностью в отрыве от студии и adb, я имел ввиду запуск через терминал. каким то образом запуск jar файла, но этим видимо некто не занимается нет информации.

Comment: В целом да, если вы будете использовать например физическое устройство с установленным whatsup подкююченное по кабелю с возмоностью запуска adb и напишите на автоматоре скрипт который чтото делает,  скомпилируете jar, то да это можно сделать.  Возможно даже whatsup заработает на эмуляторе. без adb. - судя по ответу скорее всего нет.